# Getting right part of web-scraped xml file into data frame in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the URL of the first website returned from Google searches using the Rvest package in R.

I seem to be able to get the URL into an XML file, but I can't transfer the right part of the XML file into a data frame.

I've used the code below.

```
url <- 'https://www.google.co.nz/search?rlz=1C1GCEB_enNZ790NZ790&ei=P4jsW6fbL4_RrQHd_K3wBw&q=auckland+university+of+technology+lifespan+development+and+communication+heal504&oq=auckland+university+of+technology+lifespan+development+and+communication+heal504&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20931.45570..45696...3.0..2.284.15672.0j63j18......0....1..gws-wiz.......0j0i71j35i39j0i67j0i131j0i131i67j0i20i263j0i13j0i22i10i30j0i22i30j33i21j33i160j33i22i29i30j33i10.xTnG49NmCBs'
googleurl <- read_html(url)
address <- html_nodes(googleurl,'.r')
address <- html_text(address)
urlname <- data.frame(address)
```

I can see the URL when I open the XML file in R as pictured in the attached image. However, when I transfer this to a data frame using html_text the relevant URL seems to be lost.

[Screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QI3h.png)

Comment: Most likely Google is using a javascript to generate the web page so rvest will not work.  Also most likely trying to scrap Google website is a violation of the terms of service of the web page, thus questions in conflict with the TOS is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

`html_text()` return text for element, you need to select `a` tag to get URL and using `html_attr()`

```
address <- html_nodes(googleurl,'.r>a')
address <- html_attr(address, "href")
```